# UTC to PDT/CDT/EDT pandas based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

"Schedule" and "City" are two columns of pandas dataframe df1. How will we convert the values in the column "Schedule" to PDT/CDT/EDT timezones based on local time of the city using PANDAS? Please note that there might be the change in date as well while converting the time from UTC to US Time Zones.

```
**Time**.                    **City**       
2014-05-01 13:48:58 UTC.     Chicago
2014-05-02 01:03:59 UTC.     New York
2014-05-14 17:02:20 UTC.     Los Angeles
```

Chicago - CDT
New York - EDT
Los Angeles - PDT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pytz package has support for multiple timezones.
The following code can convert your times to the given timezone:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pytz

city_to_timezone = {
    "New York": "US/Eastern"
    "Chicago": "US/Central"
    "Los Angeles": "US/Pacific"
}

def to_proper_timezone(time, city):
    timezone = None
    try:
        timezone = city_to_timezone[city]
    except KeyError:
        return np.nan
    tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    return parse(time).astimezone(tz)
    
df["Localized Time"] = df.apply(lambda x: to_proper_time(x["Time"], x["City"], axis=1)
```